# Move to Gmail Archive - Python Imaplib

Tags: python, gmail, imap, imaplib

I'm trying to write a script which moves a particular email to Archive after getting its text, however I've looked all over the place and tried plenty of solutions. My understanding is that when a message is archived, all of its labels are removed and it only appears in the All Mail folder.

This is my current code to try to remove any labels associated with the message, I believe that this should archive the message, however it seems to do nothing. There are no errors when running this code.

```
one, two = self.connection.store(msg_id, '-X-GM-LABELS', "\Inbox \Important \Sent \Seen")
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try parenthesizing the flags parameter, and making it a raw string so the backslashes are kept: r"(\Inbox \Important \Sent \Seen)"

Comment: This gives the same output unfortunately!

Comment: Issuing a UID MOVE command to the "[Gmail]/All Mail" mailbox does the trick. You have to find that mailbox' name using LIST first, unless you're doing this for just one locale. I have no idea how to convince the python imaplib to issue UID MOVE.

Answer (score 3):

The Delete flag is not the same as the Trash flag, so if you set Delete, it will move it to the archive by removing any excess labels

```
self.connection.store(msg_id, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
```

Comment: It doesn't move it to "archive", but deletes permanently. See https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/deleting-emails-in-python and plenty of other examples with this command (I use it myself, and it really deletes messages).
When you move a message to Trash, you can restore that manually.

Comment: UPD: it looks like sometimes you are right! This depends on your settings in advanced IMAP controls (http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2008/10/advanced-imap-settings-for-gmail.html): you can set it just to archive mails, or to delete them permanently. In fact I was mistaken, and now will have to find emails again and delete them permanently (they were removed just from my labeled folder).